# Event in tag Select work intermittently with javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, firefox

I'm using javascript to perform ajax requests every time an item is selected in a combo. To do this, the Select tag executes the Onchange event.

But I'm having trouble calling the js function that is running intermittently. There are times when the value is changed and the function is not executed.

This is the JS snippet that should be executed every time the select changes:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tbl select.detalhes').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            var id = $(this).val();
            AjaxCall(urlPrefix + 'Detalhe.aspx/Ficha', '{ id: ' + id + ' }', function (data) {
                carregarFicha(data);
            });
            $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        }
    });
```

**Source cshtml where I insert the js in @section Head**:

```html
@model IList<Round>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml";
}
@section Head
{
 <script src="@Url.NonCached("~/Scripts/Index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    <h2>Rodada</h2>    
    var textoRodadas = @Model.Count > 0 ? "Rodadas encontradas" : "Rodada encontrada";         
    <span class="total-registros"> <strong>@Model.Count</strong> @textoRodadas</span>    
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tbl" id="table-round">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col" class="ord">Rodada</th>
    <th scope="col" class="ord">Data Inicial</th>
    <th scope="col" class="ord">Data Final</th>
    <th scope="col" width="150" class="ord tits-th col-escura ">Regras</th>    
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
  
   var item = Model[i];
            var classe = "class=\"" + item.Tipo.ToString();
            if (item.Protegido == SimNao.Sim)
            {
                classe += " protegido ";
            }
            classe += i % 2 == 0 ? "\"" : " odd\"";

            var permitirCriarRegraComLances = !(item.Tipo == App.AdjudicacaoInicial);
                
            <tr @Html.Raw(classe) >
    <td class="tbl-nomeTipo-round") ">
     @Html.Hidden("id", item.Id)
     <span class="click-round tbl-nome-round">@item.Nome</span>
    </td>
    <td class="click-round tbl-data-round">
     @item.DataInicio.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    </td>
    <td class="click-round tbl-data-round">
     @item.DataFim.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    </td>
    <td class="col-escura">
      <div  class="grid-12-12 form">
      @{
      var regras = item.Regras.OrderBy(t => t.Nome).ToArray();
      }
      <span class="txt-maior ">@regras.Length</span>
      @if (regras.Length > 0)
      {
     <select class="form-txt regras" id="reg1" onchange="mudou(this)">
      <option value="" >Selecione</option>
       @foreach (var reg in regras)
       {
       <option value="@reg.Id">@reg.Nome</option>   
       }
     </select>
      }
     
      </div>     
    </td>
   </tr>            
        }
  </tbody>
 </table>
}
else
{
 <span>Sem resultados</span>
}
```

The application is only approved for Firefox and the code worked correctly until the company updated some clients with version 60.7.0. This particular version should be causing the problem. 
**We can't update all clients with others versions.**

Would anyone have any suggestions how fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following two methods:

**Method 1:**

Try this-

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
    //Add your logic
  console.log( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>
```

**Method: 2**

```js
function getval(sel)
{
    //Add your logic
  console.log( sel.value );
}
```

```html
<select onchange="getval(this);">
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've tried these methods and they both don't work. Only in another version of Firefox. Updated the version of Jquey and don't work too :/

Comment: Which version Jquey you using?

Comment: Currently we use version 1.9.1. But I upgraded to 2.1.1 and it did not help